# Adding outside wood boiler to oil furnace

Tags: hvac

I am adding an outdoor wood burner (water stove) to my home.

Water to air heat exchanger plumbed into existing ductwork for oil burner.

What are my options for running the oil burner's fan WITHOUT the oil burner firing and attempting to heat?

Could it be wired with a toggle switch in line at some point, as I have no plans to purchase oil at the current prices?

Comment: might do better at http://www.hearth.com/talk/forums/the-boiler-room-wood-boilers-and-furnaces.13/

Answer (score 2):

Just set the thermostat to the off position and turn the fan setting on the thermostat to "on". Your fan will run continuously until you set it back to "auto".

Answer (score 0):

Old Thread, but I'm going through this now...

The indoor furnace will have a "aquastat" that will have at a high temp setting (to tell the furnace when to turn off, and either a low temp setting (or a default differential, 10 or 15 degrees) to tell it when to turn on.

The outdoor boiler should have something similar, and to make this work, set the indoor high setting lower than the outdoor's low setting (again, this may be a differential point).

So I have my outdoor boiler High at 180, and its low (10 degree differential) 170;
the indoor High is at 160, and its low 140.  The indoor furnace will only go on if the fire goes out.

One issue I had, was the furnace aquastat would not go low enough (low of 180), so I had to  up the boiler setpoint to 191, and it's differential to 8, so that the demand would not get too far ahead of the boiler....  A newer aquastat solved this.